# Random numbers in 2d array java

Tags: java, arrays, random

I hava a problem, when I tried to enter random numbers (0 and 1) in a 2D array, that when I enter a number of rows and columns, the output will appear Exception in thread.

```
"main":java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds    
for length 3
at Test.main


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter number of rows");
    int row = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter number of columns");
    int column = input.nextInt();

    int matrix [][] = new int[row][column];

    for(int i = 0; i< matrix.length;i++){
        for (int j = 0; i< matrix.length;j++) {

            matrix[i][j]  = r.nextInt(2);
            System.out.print(matrix[i][j]+ " ");
            }
        System.out.println();
    }
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you chang `for (int j = 0; i< matrix.length;j++)` to `for (int j = 0; j< matrix[i].length;j++)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class xxxx {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter number of rows");
        int row = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter number of columns");
        int column = input.nextInt();

        int matrix [][] = new int[row][column];

        for(int i = 0; i< matrix.length;i++){
            for (int j = 0; j< matrix[i].length;j++) {
                matrix[i][j]  = r.nextInt(2);
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j]+ " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).